# Turn off Pear Error Handling

Tags: php, pear, php4

Apologies if this question is already answered somewhere else but I cannot find the answer and I've looked at a few of the `PEAR` error handling questions.

I have a situation with a legacy site which is still in PHP4 (I know, it is old).  Our server is now on PHP5 and ideally, over time we'd like to move to PHP7 but as it stands we cannot for the time being.

Since PHP5 switch we are getting a lot of deprecation errors and many of these relate to `PEAR`.

Here is an example:

> PHP Deprecated: Non-static method MDB::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in path/public_html/_ext/pear/MDB.php on line 222

I've looked around quite a lot too and error reporting is `off` in PHP.ini but the errors still keep spilling out to the error log and filling up the disk on the site every few days.

Can anyone provide any idea on how to turn the errors `off` in PEAR for now?

Thanks

Comment: `off` is not a valid value for the `error_reporting` setting. Please consult [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) on how to turn off reporting of certain errors.

Comment: I have added the following to the scripts which appear to be reporting the errors: - error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED); and in php.ini I have display_errors = Off.  I also mean I want to be able to stop the error reporting continuing as it is just piling up the disk usage all the time.  I'm aware that it's an old PEAR library and can't find a solution to stop it happening.  Looking for a solution to stop all deprecation issues being reported to the growing log constantly.